# binding combobox in wpf dataGrid2010

Tags: wpf

i am trying to bind combox in wpf datagrid.But when i am using the below tag in xaml it's giving me error

> "staticData:StatusList was not found.Verify that you are not missing
>   any assembly reference".

It's working fine in vs2008.But in vs2010 it's giving the mentioned error.

`<Window.Resources>
<staticData:StatusList x:Key="StatusList"/>
</Window.Resources>`

Some one plz help if got my problem i have given my code below:-

```
<Window x:Class="demotest.DynamicBindGridDemo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
    Title="ComboBox DataGrid WPF" Height="300" Width="616" 
     xmlns:staticData="clr-namespace:demotest"
xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">
<Window.Resources>
    <staticData:StatusList x:Key="StatusList"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Subject}" Header="Subject" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Height="22" 
                                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RaisedBy}" Header="Raised By" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Snehasis

Comment: Looks like you forgot to declare `staticData:StatusList` property. Can you provide the code for the demotest.StatusList property declaration?

Comment: Please show us the declaration of the StatusList in code

Answer (score 0):

your title and your question are not really related. but nevertheless, can you check your project settings. maybe you have the client profile and not the .Net4.0 profile. if not check the namespace for your staticData

is you StatusList in the Namespace demotest?

```
namespace demotest
{
   public class StatusList : List<string>
   {
     //...
   }    
}
```

i tried your xaml and it works

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have mentioed where i got the error.now i am putting my total xaml code:-